# Quotient map $f$ from the $n$-sphere to the $n$-disk

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to construct a quotient map $f$ from the $n$-sphere $S^n$ to the $n$-disk $D^n$, in which $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})=f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,-x_{n+1})$. The goal is to show that $S^n/\sim_f$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$.  (Is this the right way to go about it?)

I've been looking at the stereographic projection for inspiration, but haven't come up with anything. I only just started learning about topology. Any hints?

Comment: You want to first define an equivalence relation on the sphere which it seems you have done. Then you need to define your bijection from the sphere (more specifically from Equivalence classes of sphere) to the disk.

Comment: If you're willing to go the other way, you can get the homeomorphism directly: $x\mapsto (2\sqrt {1-\|x\|^2}x,2\|x\|^2-1)$